Merge two different tables where one key is a tuple and the other is an integer
I am trying to merge two dataframes based on their common 'userID':
topUsersRating=topUsers.merge(ratings_df, left_on='userId', right_on='userId', how='inner')

The type of 'userId' in topUsers is recognized as an object (for example the number 75 is shown as (75,)) and as a result, I got this error message:

You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns for key 'userId'. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

I have tried to change the object datatype to int with different methods but they didn't work.
How can I solve this problem?

You Can try Converting the dataframe column to the required data type using astype
topUsers['userId'] =  topUsers['userId'].astype('int64')

Post converting the datatype of the column you can perfrom the merge.

I have checked it before but I got this error: "setting an array element with a sequence."
